# Inserting NA in blank values from web scraping

Tags: r, web-scraping, na

I am working on scraping some data into a data frame, and am getting some empty fields, where I would instead prefer to have NA. I have tried na.strings, but am either placing it in the wrong place or it just isn't working, and I tried to gsub anything that was whitespace from beginning of line to end, but that didn't work.

```
htmlpage <- read_html("http://www.gourmetsleuth.com/features/wine-cheese-pairing-guide")
sugPairings <- html_nodes(htmlpage, ".meta-wrapper")
suggestions <- html_text(sugPairings)
suggestions <- gsub("\\r\\n", '', suggestions)
```

How can I sub out the blank fields with NA, either once it is added to the data frame, or before adding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rvest::html_text` has an build in trimming option setting `trim=TRUE`.
After you have done this you can use e.g. `ifelse` to test for an empty string (`==""`) or use `nzchar`.

I full you could do this:

```
html_nodes(htmlpage, ".meta-wrapper") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE) %>% ifelse(. == "", NA, .)
```

or this:

```
res <- html_nodes(htmlpage, ".meta-wrapper") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)
res[!nzchar(res)] <- NA_character_
```

@Richard Scriven improvement:

```
html_nodes(htmlpage, ".meta-wrapper") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE) %>% replace(!nzchar(.), NA)
```

Comment: Nice one.  Your `ifelse()` call at the end of the chain could also be `replace(!nzchar(.), NA)` so that the second block could be a complete chain

Comment: Just added it. Thanks